# String replace with backslashes in Python

Tags: python, string, backslash

I'm trying to do a simple replacement of " " with "\s" (the literal \s, not some sort of backslash escape). This is what I think should happen:

```
>>> 'asdf hjkl'.replace(' ', '\s')
'asdf\shjkl'
```

I did this:

```
>>> 'asdf hjkl'.replace(' ', '\s')
'asdf\\shjkl'
>>> 'asdf hjkl'.replace(' ', '\\s')
'asdf\\shjkl'
```

Neither returns what I expected, and I can't for the life of me understand what's going on. What input do I have to use to get my expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting what you want. It just doesn't look that way in the REPL:

```
>>> 'asdf hjkl'.replace(' ', '\s')[4]
'\\'
```

As you can see, that's one character, not two.

Try `print`ing it:

```
>>> print 'asdf hjkl'.replace(' ', '\s')
asdf\shjkl
```

Comment: So when does the REPL act like this?

Comment: @arxanas: It's not so much about the REPL, the REPL just uses `repr` to print objects (except `None`) that result from the statements you enter. And a string's `repr` is a string literal that, when evaluated as Python expression, gives the same string.

Answer (score 2):

The result is only displayed,
try the following,

```
a = 'asdf hjkl'.replace(' ','\s')
print a
```